# Ble multiple connection

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

is it possible to connect multiple sensor tags via Bluetooth low energy? In the app provided by TI, the sensor tag is the server, and app is client. So, it is possible for a single client to connect multiple servers?

Comment: Yes it is possible. But try to google a little more. There have been a zillion questions about this.

Comment: can you suggest me any link which can tell me how to do it with Android .i have been searching for this for the past two weeks

Comment: The official page http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth-le.html describes how you can scan, connect, discover, etc. peripherals. If you implement the functionality it for one peripheral and consider multiple peripherals in places where it's needed, you'll have the multiple peripheral solution at the end. There's even a video on the page that will explain in detail the whole process.

Comment: Have a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21237093/android-4-3-how-to-connect-to-multiple-bluetooth-low-energy-devices/27412693#27412693) regarding multiple BLE connections on Android.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

YES, it is possible to connect from one application to multiple BLE devices

On the other side, at at the moment, Android BLE stack (BlueDroid) seems to have synchronous nature (may be it is inspired by Samsung stack from 4.2 devices , where this behaviour was documented as discuseed here [Has native Android BLE GATT implementation synchronous nature?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18011816/has-native-android-ble-gatt-implementation-synchronous-nature)).

This mean, that if one operation is in progress, othes are ignored, so you have to implement e.g., queue of requests to be sure that just one characteristic read/write is in progress.

More over, Andorid BLE stack is at the moment quite unstable, as discussed in many threads, e.g, here [Android 4.3 Bluetooth Low Energy unstable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17870189/android-4-3-bluetooth-low-energy-unstable)

Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

You're terminology doesn't seem to be quite correct, but if you're trying to ask whether it's possible to connect multiple senrors or similar to one phone, the answer to that should be yes.

I'd recommend you to take a look at [this](https://devzone.nordicsemi.com/index.php/what-is-a-client-and-server-in-ble) and [this](https://bluegiga.zendesk.com/entries/25053373--REFERENCE-BLE-master-slave-GATT-client-server-and-data-RX-TX-basics), to better understand the roles in BLE.