# Writing data to Bluetooth LE characteristic in Android

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

Although similar questions have been asked but it's slightly different. I know how to pass data to a connected BLE device but I think I'm doing something wrong for which I need help.
The code below contains all the methods from my class that is extending BroadcastReceiver.

1. I scan and connect to a device specified by `PEN_ADDRESS`.
2. In `onServicesDiscovered` method I look for a service whose `UUID` contains `abcd`.
3. Then I loop through the characteristics of this services and look for three characteristics with specific strings in their `UUID`.
4. The third characteristic is a writable characteristic in which I'm trying to write data by calling the method `writeCharac(mGatt,writeChar1,123);`
   The data `123` passed above is just a dummy data.

I debugged my code while trying writing to this characteristic but on putting breakpoints inside the `writeCharac` method, I found that the `status` value is false, indicating that the write was not successful.
Am I missing something here? Please do help!

```
public class BackgroundReceiverFire extends BroadcastReceiver {
Context context;
private BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;
private BluetoothGatt mGatt;
private BluetoothLeService mBluetoothLeService;
private boolean mScanning;
private final String TAG = "READING: ";
private BluetoothDevice mDevice;
private Handler mHandler;
private static final int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 1;
private final String PEN_ADDRESS = "FB:23:AF:42:5C:56";
// Stops scanning after 10 seconds.
private static final long SCAN_PERIOD = 10000;

    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        this.context = context;
        Toast.makeText(context, "Started Scanning", LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        initializeBluetooth();
        startScan();
    }

    private void initializeBluetooth() {
        mHandler = new Handler();

        // Use this check to determine whether BLE is supported on the device.  Then you can
        // selectively disable BLE-related features.
        // Initializes a Bluetooth adapter.  For API level 18 and above, get a reference to
        // BluetoothAdapter through BluetoothManager.
        final BluetoothManager bluetoothManager =
                (BluetoothManager) context.getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
        mBluetoothAdapter = bluetoothManager.getAdapter();

        // Checks if Bluetooth is supported on the device.
        if (mBluetoothAdapter == null) {
            Toast.makeText(this.context, "No Bluetooth", LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }
    }

    private void startScan() {
        scanLeDevice(true);
    }

    private void stopScan() {
        scanLeDevice(false);
    }

    private void scanLeDevice(final boolean enable) {
        if (enable) {
            // Stops scanning after a pre-defined scan period.
            mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    mScanning = false;
                    mBluetoothAdapter.stopLeScan(mLeScanCallback);
                }
            }, SCAN_PERIOD);

            mScanning = true;
            //Scanning for the device
            mBluetoothAdapter.startLeScan(mLeScanCallback);
        } else {
            mScanning = false;
            mBluetoothAdapter.stopLeScan(mLeScanCallback);
        }
    }

    private BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback mLeScanCallback =
            new BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onLeScan(final BluetoothDevice device, int rssi, byte[] scanRecord) {
                    if (device.getAddress().matches(PEN_ADDRESS)) {
                        connectBluetooth(device);
                        Toast.makeText(context, "Device Found: " + device.getAddress(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    }
                }
            };

    private void connectBluetooth(BluetoothDevice insulinPen) {
        if (mGatt == null) {
            Log.d("connectToDevice", "connecting to device: " + insulinPen.toString());
            mDevice = insulinPen;
            mGatt = insulinPen.connectGatt(context, true, gattCallback);
            scanLeDevice(false);// will stop after first device detection
        }
    }

    private void enableBluetooth() {
        if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            mBluetoothAdapter.enable();
        }
        scanLeDevice(true);
    }

    private void disableBluetooth() {
        if (mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            mBluetoothAdapter.disable();
        }
    }

    private final BluetoothGattCallback gattCallback = new BluetoothGattCallback() {


        @Override
        public void onConnectionStateChange(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status, int newState) {
            Log.i("onConnectionStateChange", "Status: " + status);
            switch (newState) {
                case BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTED:
                    gatt.discoverServices();
                    break;
                case BluetoothProfile.STATE_DISCONNECTED:
                    Log.e("gattCallback", "STATE_DISCONNECTED");
                    Log.i("gattCallback", "reconnecting...");
                    BluetoothDevice mDevice = gatt.getDevice();
                    mGatt = null;
                    connectBluetooth(mDevice);
                    break;
                default:
                    Log.e("gattCallback", "STATE_OTHER");
                    break;
            }

        }

        public void onServicesDiscovered(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status) {
            mGatt = gatt;
            List<BluetoothGattService> services = mGatt.getServices();
            Log.i("onServicesDiscovered", services.toString());
            Iterator<BluetoothGattService> serviceIterator = services.iterator();
            while(serviceIterator.hasNext()){
                BluetoothGattService bleService = serviceIterator.next();
                if(bleService.getUuid().toString().contains("abcd")){
                    //Toast.makeText(context,"Got the service",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    BluetoothGattCharacteristic readChar1 = bleService.getCharacteristics().get(0);
                    for (BluetoothGattDescriptor descriptor : readChar1.getDescriptors()) {
                        descriptor.setValue(BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_INDICATION_VALUE);
                        mGatt.writeDescriptor(descriptor);
                        mGatt.setCharacteristicNotification(readChar1, true);
                    }
                    //mGatt.readCharacteristic(readChar1);

                    BluetoothGattCharacteristic readChar2 = bleService.getCharacteristics().get(1);
                    for (BluetoothGattDescriptor descriptor : readChar2.getDescriptors()) {
                        descriptor.setValue(BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_INDICATION_VALUE);
                        mGatt.writeDescriptor(descriptor);
                        mGatt.setCharacteristicNotification(readChar2, true);
                    }
                    //mGatt.readCharacteristic(readChar2);

                    BluetoothGattCharacteristic writeChar1 = bleService.getCharacteristics().get(2);
                    for (BluetoothGattDescriptor descriptor : writeChar1.getDescriptors()) {
                        descriptor.setValue( BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_INDICATION_VALUE);
                        mGatt.writeDescriptor(descriptor);
                        mGatt.setCharacteristicNotification(writeChar1, true);
                    }
                    writeCharac(mGatt,writeChar1,123);
                }
            }

            //gatt.readCharacteristic(therm_char);

        }
        public void writeCharac(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic charac, int value ){
            if (mBluetoothAdapter == null || gatt == null) {
                Log.w(TAG, "BluetoothAdapter not initialized");
                return;
            }
/*
            BluetoothGattCharacteristic charac = gattService
                    .getCharacteristic(uuid);
*/
            if (charac == null) {
                Log.e(TAG, "char not found!");
            }

            int unixTime = value;
            String unixTimeString = Integer.toHexString(unixTime);
            byte[] byteArray = hexStringToByteArray(unixTimeString);
            charac.setValue(byteArray);
            boolean status = mGatt.writeCharacteristic(charac);
            if(status){
                Toast.makeText(context,"Written Successfully",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(context,"Error writing characteristic",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

        public byte[] hexStringToByteArray(String s) {
            int len = s.length();
            byte[] data = new byte[len/2];

            for(int i = 0; i < len; i+=2){
                data[i/2] = (byte) ((Character.digit(s.charAt(i), 16) << 4) + Character.digit(s.charAt(i+1), 16));
            }

            return data;
        }

        public void onCharacteristicRead(BluetoothGatt gatt,
                                         BluetoothGattCharacteristic
                                                 characteristic, int status) {
            Log.i("onCharacteristicRead", characteristic.toString());
            String characteristicValue = characteristic.getValue().toString();
            Log.d("CHARACTERISTIC VALUE: ", characteristicValue);
            gatt.disconnect();
        }

        public void onCharacteristicChanged(BluetoothGatt gatt,
                                            BluetoothGattCharacteristic
                                                    characteristic) {
            String value = characteristic.getValue().toString();
            Log.d(TAG,value);
        }

    };
```

Answer (score 6):

Although the BLE API is asynchronous in nature, the actual signal transmission is inevitably synchronous. You have to wait for the previous connect/write/read call to callback before starting any connecting/writing/reading operation.

In your code `onServicesDiscovered(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status)` function, you called `mGatt.writeDescriptor(descriptor)` twice before trying to write the characteristic. The API will refuse to start your write request as it is being busy writing the descriptor, and return false for your `mGatt.writeCharacteristic(charac)` call.

So just wait for the writeDescriptor to callback before calling writeCharacteristic. This nature is not well documented but you can find some source [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18011816/has-native-android-ble-gatt-implementation-synchronous-nature) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17870189/android-4-3-bluetooth-low-energy-unstable?rq=1).

Comment: Thanks so much @reTs. I'll try it and update if it works. Just one doubt, I also intend to read two characteristics (please see commented lines - `gatt.readCharacteristic(readChar1);` and `gatt.readCharacteristic(readChar2);`). I thought for each characteristic read/write, I need to call `mGatt.writeDescriptor(descriptor)`. I think I understood it incorrectly.

Comment: @abhinavDAIICT You try to write BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_INDICATION_VALUE to the descriptor, which is totally irrelevant to read/write process. Those lines of codes are used to turn on indication of characteristic, which is completely another type of transmission.

Comment: This fixed my issue when i tried to update all my values at start in the onServicesDiscovered callback and characteristic wasn't being written, since i was also writing to the descriptor.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @reTs and @pooja for suggestions. The issue was due to these two lines 
    `mGatt = null`
`connectBluetooth(mDevice);`
in STATE_DISCONNECTED. I had figured it out but don't remember the exact reason. Posting it just in case it is helpful.