# Android BLE BluetoothGatt.writeDescriptor() return sometimes false

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm trying to write BLE Android app. I found that sometimes when I call 
[BluetoothGatt.writeDescriptor()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothGatt.html#writeDescriptor(android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattDescriptor)) it returns false.

I have not found in documentation any note of limitation to this function. But ppl on stack overflow says that I need to wait for [BluetoothGattCallback.onDescriptorWrite()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothGattCallback.html#onDescriptorWrite(android.bluetooth.BluetoothGatt,%20android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattDescriptor,%20int)) before I try to write another descriptor.

Here is one reply saying that [BLE is busy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36169096/1093607) with writeDescriptor() and can not do other write.

Here is [another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24178815/1093607) saying that you can not call twice writeCharacteristic().

My questions are

- is it really true?
- is there really missing some internal android API buffer for serializing BLE requests and every developer has to do it on it's own?
- Is it true for different functions? For example when I call `writeDescriptor()` I understand I can not call second time `writeDescriptor()` before I receive `onDescriptorWrite()`. But do I have to wait for `onDescriptorWrite()` when I want to call `writeCharacteristic()`?
- Also if there is inter-function dependency then what else function have this limitation (namely: `readCharacteristic()`, `readDescriptor()`, `requestMtu()`...)?
- And additionally is there interdependency between BluetoothGattServer and BluetoothGatt. So for example when I call `BluetoothGattServer.notifyCharacteristicChanged()` shall I wait for[`BluetoothGattServerCallback.onNotificationSent`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothGattServerCallback.html#onNotificationSent(android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice,%20int)) before I can call `BluetoothGatt.writeDescriptor()` or `BluetoothGatt.writeCharacteristic()`? (BTW praise for google documentation `onNotificationSent()` is by luck documented properly. Doc says:

> When multiple notifications are to be sent, an application must wait
>   for this callback to be received before sending additional
>   notifications.

- Lastly having all this questions - I feel that Android BLE API is under-documented. Or am I wrong and there is documented somewhere what are allowed methods calling sequences? If yes can you please point me to such documentation? If not is there some channel we can open issue with google and ask them to add to documentation something? I mean it may not be much text - some function like `onNotificationSent()` is arleady properly documented. They just need to copy this sentence to other functions.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The documentation lacks information. However you can read the source code to find out the rules, which (currently) are the following:

For each `BluetoothGatt` object, you can only have one outstanding request at a time, including `requestMtu`, `readCharacteristic`, `writeCharacteristic`, `readDescriptor`, `writeDescriptor` and `executeReliableWrite`. So if you issue a read request you need to wait for the read response before you issue a write request. While they implemented the code that returns false if there is an ongoing operation in [BluetoothGatt.java](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/bluetooth/BluetoothGatt.java), they forgot to do this for `requestMtu`, so if you have multiple requests at a time where `requestMtu` is one of them, you will get random errors sooner or later (in the latest versions at the time of this post).

So yes, every developer has to manually serialize the requests. Note that the Bluetooth stack actually has a queue of requests, but it is limited to only one request per client (i.e. BluetoothGatt object). So if two apps on the same phone talk to the same device simultaneously you will never get "busy" errors. The only exception is if you use Write Without Response for which the current data flow implementation is quite buggy (see https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37121017 which Google seems to have ignored).

You can send notifications at the same time as you write a characteristic, since the server and client roles are separated.

Regarding updating the documentation, you can always try to file an issue at https://issuetracker.google.com (but I get the feeling nobody reads that), or, since Android is open source, send a pull request to https://android-review.googlesource.com/ which updates the Javadoc from which the documentation is generated.

Comment: great explanation! hard to find this answer

Comment: how do you wait for a response?

Comment: Just wait for the corresponding callback to be called. For example if you call `writeCharacteristic` you need to implement `onCharacteristicWrite` in your `BluetoothGattCallback`.

Comment: I had a same issue, I found this one which maintains queue https://gist.github.com/SoulAuctioneer/ee4cb9bc0b3785bbdd51

Comment: That code doesn't seem to be thread safe, so it probably may suffer from race conditions. Note that `onCharacteristicWrite` is called from a Binder thread, which is usually not the thread you initiate operations from. Hence txQueue might be used by two threads simultaneously. The code also suffers from an issue that if you connect to a different Bluetooth address, you leak the previous BluetoothGatt object (the author forgot it must be closed).