# BluetoothGatt.writeCharacteristic return false half the time

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

Actually I make an update through Bluetooth. In first time I erase the memory bank and then I write an hexa File on it.

But half the time an update will don't work correctly, for every data I transfer the first writeCharacteristic will return false.
It happen on an entire update half the time.

I try in debug mode but the method never return false in that case, of course it's probably a delay problem, but I can't increase the time.

This is my code for send my data :

```
public void sendTX(final byte[] sMessage) {
        BluetoothGattService service = mBluetoothGatt.getService(UUID_SERVICE_SERIAL);
        if (service != null && sMessage != null) {
            Log.d(TAG,"sMessage : " + sMessage);

            final BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic = service.getCharacteristic(UUID_TX);
            if (characteristic != null) {

                Thread thread = new Thread() {
                    public void run() {

                        if (sMessage.length > 20) {

                            for (int i = 0; i < sMessage.length; i += 20) {
                                byte[] byteArraySplit = Arrays.copyOfRange(sMessage, i, i + 20 < sMessage.length ? i + 20 : sMessage.length);
                                characteristic.setWriteType(BluetoothGattCharacteristic.WRITE_TYPE_NO_RESPONSE);
                                characteristic.setValue(byteArraySplit);
                                while(!mBluetoothGatt.writeCharacteristic(characteristic)) {
                                    try {
                                        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(15);
                                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }
                                 }
                            }
                        } else {
                            characteristic.setWriteType(BluetoothGattCharacteristic.WRITE_TYPE_NO_RESPONSE);
                            characteristic.setValue(sMessage);
                            while(!mBluetoothGatt.writeCharacteristic(characteristic)){

                            try {
                                 TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(15);
                               } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                 e.printStackTrace();
                              }

                            }

                        }

                    }
                };
                thread.start();
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "UUID TX null");

            }
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "Service BLE null");
        }
    }
```

And this is the code of the native writeCharacteristic method :

```
public boolean writeCharacteristic(BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic) {
        if ((characteristic.getProperties() & BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_WRITE) == 0
            && (characteristic.getProperties() &
                BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_WRITE_NO_RESPONSE) == 0) return false;

        if (VDBG) Log.d(TAG, "writeCharacteristic() - uuid: " + characteristic.getUuid());
        if (mService == null || mClientIf == 0 || characteristic.getValue() == null) return false;

        BluetoothGattService service = characteristic.getService();
        if (service == null) return false;

        BluetoothDevice device = service.getDevice();
        if (device == null) return false;

        synchronized(mDeviceBusy) {
            if (mDeviceBusy) return false;
            mDeviceBusy = true;
        }

        try {
            mService.writeCharacteristic(mClientIf, device.getAddress(),
                characteristic.getInstanceId(), characteristic.getWriteType(),
                AUTHENTICATION_NONE, characteristic.getValue());
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            Log.e(TAG,"",e);
            mDeviceBusy = false;
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never use timeouts to try to workaround this issue. The proper way is to wait for the callback and then perform the next request. See [Android BLE BluetoothGatt.writeDescriptor() return sometimes false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47097298/android-ble-bluetoothgatt-writedescriptor-return-sometimes-false/47103533#47103533).

Comment: Yes it's right, I've modfied my code and it work a little better. Thanks for the help.