# Example for subscribing for BLE indicate in android

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth

I have connected to a bluetooth device.
I am able to read charectristic using

```
mGatt.readCharacteristic(getMiliService().getCharacteristic(uuid));
```

But I am not able to register indicate for a characteristic.
What I tried

```
boolean flag1 = m_Gatt.setCharacteristicNotification(bluetoothgattcharacteristic, flag);

BluetoothGattDescriptor descriptor= bluetoothgattcharacteristic.getDescriptor(Helper.UUID_DESCRIPTOR_CLIENT_CHARACTERISTIC_CONFIGURATION);
descriptor.setValue(BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_NOTIFICATION_VALUE);
mGatt.writeDescriptor(descriptor);
descriptor.setValue(BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_INDICATION_VALUE);
mGatt.writeDescriptor(descriptor);
```

and waiting for

> onCharacteristicChanged(BluetoothGatt bluetoothgatt, final BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic)

method getting called. which never happend.
I am not sure what I am missing here.
Can anyone give a working example for indicate?

Answer (score 1):

It is important for you to note that Android BLE stack allows you to write characteristics one at a time only.

And this is a working example that helped me a lot:

https://github.com/devunwired/accessory-samples/blob/master/BluetoothGatt/src/com/example/bluetoothgatt/MainActivity.java

Comment: How will we know the previous characteristic writing is completed or not?

Comment: Is there any difference between notification and indication in android? will the ACK sent by android directly or we have to send them manually?

Comment: Yes, It depends on the Bluetooth Profile implementation inside the bluetooth device. It either uses "Notification" or "Indication" for posting updates. So you'll have to find out which one your device uses.

Comment: Try writing one charateristic and check if callback is called. Then you should nest calls, only after previous is completed

Comment: Tried that also. Tried writing 1 without another. still same problem

Comment: Álvaro Pérez Soria  I got the issue. Its the device propery, that we have to write a control descriptor with certain byte to activate notification flow. Now its working. I did not have proper documentation for this device thanks for your reply

Comment: I moved writing of characteristics in to an asynchronous thread

Answer (score 0):

this [project](https://github.com/Fakher-Hakim/android-BluetoothLeGatt) allow you to connect to a BLE device, and contain all the methods of permission: `write`,`read`,`indicate` and `notification`

for the indication, you must set the `CCCD` to it's value. you will find this in the project.